# ошибка java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, servlet

Не работает подключение БД с сервлетом. Помогите понять в чем проблема.

```
public class ServletDay extends HttpServlet {

    static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/DataBase";
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "root";
    public String res;

    String resQ = null;
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    int dayID = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    Connection connection;
    String query = "select * from DataBase.table WHERE ID =" + dayID;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS); //Коннект к БД
            if (!connection.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("Connect to DB");
            }

        Statement statement = null;

            statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                resQ = resultSet.getString("Text");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.println("<h1>" + resQ + "</h1>");
            }
         //   String res = resQ;
        } catch (SQLException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Исключение:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1109)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.servlets.ServletDay.doGet(ServletDay.java:34)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1347)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

В десктопе все прекрасно работает и зависимость точно подключена.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Положите библиотеку mysql (mysql-connector-java-5.1.29.jar или вроде того) в каталог `lib` внутри Томката и перезапустите Томкат.