# Не получается сделать запрос в бд из идеи

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, jdbc

я пытаюсь передать запрос в бд из intellij Idea
у меня стоит 3307 потому что я решил вначале поменять и в ней ошибки нет

### мой код:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {


                String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/test";

        Connection dbConnect;

        String name = "Mahmoud";
        String age = "17";
        String email = "makhmud@mail.com";


        try {

            Class.forName(" com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            dbConnect = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, dbuser, dbPass);
            String insert = String.format(
                    "INSERT INTO m (m, m, m) VALUES (?,?,?)",
                    constant.USER_TABLE,
                    constant.USER_NAME,
                    constant.USER_AGE,
                    constant.USER_EMAIL);
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnect.prepareStatement(insert);

            preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, age);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, email);

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    }`
```

### ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:391)д
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:382)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ошибка java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626285/); [Не находит драйвер com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1305974/)

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка в строке `Class.forName(" com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");`
лишний пробел в начале имени класса
попробуйте так:
`Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");`

Comment: Точно, опечатка!

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникает потому, что библиотека с драйвером не указана на пути classpath . Ее можно добавить с помощью аргумента -classpath в командной строке. Из идеи в окне зависимостей добавить библиотеку.

Можно также библиотеку положить в `META-INF/lib`, а в manifest.mf прописать свойство `Class-Path`, примерно как в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/873225/204920) ответе.

При этом следует собирать jar-файл для запуска с командной строки. Например так:

```
java -jar MyApp.jar
```

Comment: Если этот ответ вам помог, пометьте его как принятый. Флажок я бы поставил слева от ответа. Также стоит проголосовать за ответ, который помог вам, чтобы помочь другим выбрать правильный ответ.